# Maxima - Substitutions in Equations - let() and letsimp() without effect

Tags: equation, substitution, maxima

My own equation is a bit longer, but the following example shows perfectly where I struggle at the moment.
So far I have been using the `let()` and `letsimp()` function 
to substitute longer terms in an equation, 
but in this example they have no effect:

```
(%i1) eq: ((2*u+a^2+d) * y+x)/2*a = x;
                                    2
                     a ((2 u + d + a ) y + x)
(%o1)                ------------------------ = x
                                2
(%i2) let(2*u+a^2+d, %beta);
                                       2
(%o2)                       2 u + d + a  --> %beta
(%i3) letsimp(eq);
                                        2
                         a ((2 u + d + a ) y + x)
(%o3)                    ------------------------ = x
                                    2
```

What is the preferred way to replace `2*u+a^2+d` with `%beta` in this sample equation? 
And why has `letsimp()` no effect?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`letsimp` applies only to "*" expressions. You could try `subst`.

Comment: Thank you @robert, that worked great! For other cases I had to keep `letsimp` as `subst` did not work. So one works where the other fails and vice versa, it seems one has to keep trying both from time to time :-) .

Comment: Just found `ratsubst()` in the documentation.  It works much better for my equations